# Where to find Firebase server key, I have enabled Cloud Messaging API V1 but i can't find it

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I'm having trouble finding the server key, I have set up a new project in firebase console, in my project settings I have enabled Cloud Messaging API V1, but cant see the server key my Cloud Messaging is showing disabled, where can I find it? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

you have to enable the Cloud Messaging API from the [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/googlecloudmessaging.googleapis.com?authuser=0&project=courseflutter-15e95&hl=en) by clicking on this link **or** in firebase console there are three dots and clicking on the "Manage API in Google Cloud Console"after enabling the API go back to firebase and refresh then you will get the FCM key for messaging

[image]